# Show a report on a Home Page component using VF

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I am trying to show an Opportunity report on a Home Page component in Lightning using VF. It's working in Classic, but in Lightning, it says "XXXXXXXXXX.my.salesforce.com refused to connect"

Code:

`<apex:page >
  <apex:outputPanel >
     <script> location.href="/00O5D000000PZILUA4?isdtp=vw"; </script>
  </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>`

I assume VF needs to look different for LIghtning, but I am not a developer and I don't know any coding, so I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

-Ivan

edit:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce gets loaded in a frame in Lightning. If your page is having Javascript which tries to interact with page such **window.onlocation**, they are not supported in Lightning.

As a workaround, you can use **analytics:reportChart**.

> Use this component to add Salesforce report charts to a Visualforce
>   page. You can filter chart data to show specific results. The
>   component is available in API version 29.0 or later.
>
> Before you add a report chart, check that the source report has a
>   chart in Salesforce app.

```
<analytics:reportChart cacheAge="10" cacheResults="false" 
                               reportid="00O5D000000PZILUA4" size="large" 
                               >
        </analytics:reportChart>
```

If you want to filter your report, you can also do that. Filter a report chart by fields in addition to field filters already in the report to get specific data. Note that a report can have up to 20 field filters. A filter has these attributes in the form of a JSON string:

**column**: The API name of the field that you want to filter on.

**operator**:The API name of the condition you want to filter a field by. For example, to filter by "not equal to," use the API name "notEqual."

**value**: The filter criteria.

For example,

```
[{column:'STAGE_NAME',operator:'equals',value:'Prospecting'},{column:'EXP_AMOUNT',operator:'greaterThan',value:'75000'}]
```

Read more here:- [analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm)

Comment: Hi Sanket,

Thank you for your answer.

I don't have a chart in the report and I don't want to show it on the home page.
If I understand you correctly, I can't show the report on the home page. Right?

I am not sure how to use your code. Probably need something before or after it, but, as I said, I am not a developer and I don't know how to write code.

I will add a screenshot from my home page from Classic in the post so it's clear what I am talking about.